# Display alertbox over a dialogbox by pressing the back button

Tags: android

I am trying to display the alertbox over the dialog box by pressing the back Button to delete that dialog box. I have created this dialog box in a switch statement. I tried it by using every possible aspects, but it didn't help
Heres my code:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (arg2) {
                case 0:
                    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            Listitem.this);
                    dialog.setTitle("kya h");
                    dialog.setMessage("kuch ni");
                    dialog.setCancelable(true);
                    dialog.create();
                    dialog.show();

                    dialog.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                                // finish();
                                // dialog.dismiss();
                                exitByBackKey();
                            }
                            return false;
                        }

                        private void exitByBackKey() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(Listitem.this);
                            alertbox.setMessage("Do u want to exit");
                            alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(
                                                DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated
                                            // method stub
                                            finish();
                                            dialog.cancel();

                                        }
                                    })
                                    .setNegativeButton(
                                            "No",
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(
                                                        DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int which) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated
                                                    // method stub

                                                }
                                            }).show();

                        }
                    });
                    break;

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the behaviour of the back button all you need to do is to override the `onBackPressed()` method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage("Do u want to exit")
        .setNegativeButton("No")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                finish();
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }).create().show();
}
```

Make sure `dialog` is accessible by the `onBackPressed()` method.